# how to configure the welcome-file-list tag in web.xml to different path like <welcome-file> HTML/welcome.html </welcome-file>

Tags: html, xml, jsp, servlets

How to configure the welcome-file tag in web.xml to different path like HTML/welcome.html.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>HTML/welcome.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

please help me.

Folder structure is:

```
Web-inf  
>HTML
web.xml
index.html
```

p.s HTML is a folder. I want to use a page inside the HTML folder as my welcome page.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You must put HTML folder outside WEB-INF.
The `web.xml` should be inside WEB-INF.

```
WEB-INF
  |_ web.xml
HTML
  |_ index.html
  |_ welcome.html
```

Doing that, your web.xml file will be like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>html/welcome.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I hope I could help you.